# Error while trying to insert text to a Text widget from an outside function after mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

This is the part of the code where im having trouble with:

```
#file1:

from tkinter import *
import file2
chat = Text()

def createGUI():
    main = Tk()
    main.title("main")
    main.geometry("1280x720")
    main.resizable()

    global chat
    chat = Text(main)
    chat.place(x=775, y=20, height=575, width=450)

    file2.StartThread()

    mainloop()

def InsertMSG(message):
    global chat
    chat.insert(1.0,  message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CreateGUI()
```

In the other file, this is the code:

```
#file 2:
import file1
import threading

def StartThread():
    listening = threading.Thread(target=listen)
    listening.start()

def listen():
    while True:
        message = input("Enter your message")
        file1.InsertMSG(message)
```

Quick note, in the actual code the message that's supposed to be printed in the Text widget is being received from a client and transpored throught a socket, but this part works perfectly so it's irelevant to the problem.
I'm pretty certain that the Text isn't displayed due to the fact that I'm trying to insert the text after the `mainloop()` statement, but I have no idea how to fix it. (I've saw some solutions using `tk.update_idletasks()` and `tk.update()` but I couldn't seem to make it work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error. Though, if you are trying to insert the text after `main loop` finishes you are likely trying to insert into a widget that has already been destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I actually dont get any error message, the Text widget just doesn't work as intended, no message is being showed.

Comment: first: all GUIs don't like to work in threads and you should rather change text in widget in main thread. Second: `input()` looks stupid when you create GUI. Maybe you should use `Entry` or one of `messagebox` to get text in GUI. And then you don't need thread because they don't block `mainloop`

Comment: problem can be because you have two `chat` in code - and when `file2` imports `file1` then it creates new `chat = Text()` which is not part of window - so it send text to widget which is not displayed. You should send `chat` as parameter `StartThread(chat)` and it should send it to listener - but it may not work because GUIs don't like to change value in widgets in separated threads, and it may need Queue to send text to main thread which will use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run function which gets text from queue and put in correct `chat`

Answer (score 1):

When you start `file1` then it creates `Text(main)` but when `file2` imports `file1` then it doesn't get this `chat` but it creates new `chat = Text()` which is not displayed in window. So later it sends text to Text which you can't see.

You should send `chat` as parameter to function in `file2`

```
file2.StartThread(chat)
```

and it should send it as parameter to `listener`

```
def StartThread(chat):
    listening = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(chat,))
    listening.start()
```

and it should send it as parameter to `InsertMSG`

```
def listen(chat):

    # ...code ...

    file1.InsertMSG(chat, message)
```

and it should get it

```
def InsertMSG(chat, message):
    chat.insert(1.0,  message)
```

This way it will use the same Text as it displays in window.

---

**file1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import file2

def CreateGUI():
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.title("main")
    main.geometry("1280x720")
    main.resizable()

    chat = tk.Text(main)
    chat.place(x=775, y=20, height=575, width=450)

    file2.StartThread(chat)

    main.mainloop()

def InsertMSG(chat, message):
    chat.insert(1.0,  message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CreateGUI()
```

**file2.py**

```
import file1
import threading

def StartThread(chat):
    listening = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(chat,))
    listening.start()

def listen(chat):
    while True:
        message = input("Enter your message: ")
        file1.InsertMSG(chat, message)
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

But I would rather use `tkinter.Entry()` to get text - and it wouldn't need thread.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

def create_gui():   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    global chat
    global entry
    
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.title("main")
    #main.geometry("1280x720")
    main.resizable()

    chat = tk.Text(main, bg='white')
    chat.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    label = tk.Label(main, text="Enter your message: ")
    label.pack()
    
    entry = tk.Entry(main, bg='white')
    entry.pack(fill='x')
    entry.bind('<Return>', insert_message)  # execute `insert_message()` when key `ENTER` pressed in `entry`

    main.mainloop()

def insert_message(event):   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    text = entry.get()
    chat.insert('end', text + '\n')
    entry.delete('0', 'end')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_gui()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I did a few modifications to your suggestion as my actual code is a bit different and more complicated than that, and it works perfectly! I really can't thank you enough, I've been stuck on it for days. @furas